# What are these wires with pre-attached connectors called?

Tags: connector, wire, identification

[image: From the "Half the battle is knowing what to search for on DigiKey" deptartment]

What are these connectors commonly called, and what would I search for if I wanted to buy sets of male/female pairs with a specific gauge of wire pre-attached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adafruit [calls](http://www.adafruit.com/products/579) this [style](http://www.adafruit.com/products/578) of connector "JST" or "[JST SM](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/JSTSM.pdf)", for the (original) manufacturer, [Japan Solderless Terminal](http://www.jst-mfg.com/company/info_e.php).

Answer (score 2):

Generically these are just polarized header connectors. Sometime they are referred to as Molex connectors, but this is just one manufacturer. (I think the Molex SPOX range seems to be the closest match)

Comment: Here's something I don't understand then: these are wire-to-wire connectors; I thought "headers" were specifically for wire-to-board connections.

Comment: The Molex SPOX page is under "wire to board" connectors, so that's not what I want, hence the down vote, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A connector with wires/cable pre-attached is often sold as a "pigtail", "preassembled cable","cable assembly"; if it is a spare part for a specific device, esp with multiple connectors attached, it might also be called a "harness".