# What is a good single conductor wire-to-wire connector?

Tags: connector, wiring

I'm currently using 3-position [JST connectors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12072/what-are-these-wires-with-pre-attached-connectors-called) with two of the wires cut off, but this is unsatisfying. The 3 position JST is also bulkier than I'd like, and has lots of "barbs" and corners to catch on things, which is undesirable for my application (wearable electronics.)

The connector will be carrying signal at 5V, so the current requirements are low.

Comment: Does the mated pin/socket set have to latch?

Comment: Friction will probably be enough, as long as it's reasonably tight.

Comment: I think you should explain what sort of connector you are looking for mechanically then maybe say what current it has to carry.

Comment: Edited to include a hint on current. As to the mechanical properties, that's part of the question. I just don't know what's out there.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for single pole "bullet" connectors. Common among RC hobbyists as a connector between battery pack and system. To make them more streamlined you could apply some heatshrink tube.

[image]

Comment: Interesting idea, but as I modified the question to say, it's signal wire so very low current. Are there smaller (read: cheaper) versions than the RC pack ones?

Comment: What is cheap to you? :) Give a figure of your price limit.